# How to get the IIS virtual dir & web application's physical paths with C# code?

Tags: .net, windows, iis

I am writing a web application deployment verification tool and I need to check the physical folder structures of Web Applicatons and Virtual Folders.

How can this be done in C#? OR more generally, interact with IIS through C# code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using the [Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) dll for superb admin features with IIS.

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();

// get the site (e.g. default)
Site site = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Default Web Site");
// get the application that you are interested in
Application myApp = site.Applications["/Dev1"];

// get the physical path of the virtual directory
Console.WriteLine(myApp.VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath);
```

Gives:

**F:\Dev\Branches\Dev1**

Comment: I found that IIS can auto-generate the script code to get certain configuration values. In C#, Shell script and javascript. But I am still trying to figure out how to get the physical path of the virtual folder and web app. If anyone found it, could you tell me? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this kind of thing using WMI:

[Using WMI to configure IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525309(v=vs.90).aspx).

[Administering IIS programatically](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9041b0a5-c314-46d9-8f56-01506687f357.mspx?mfr=true).

And you can use WMI from C# (google for "WMI C#").

So, yes, this is possible.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the good old WMI. It's meant for *management*. I almost forgot it. ;)

Comment: @smwiki - yes for *management*, but for configuration prefer to use `System.DirectoryServices` on IIS6 and `Microsoft.Web.Administration` on IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `HttpRequest` object. You can get the current URL using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`.

If you wanted to check that a virtual IIS folder existed you could try performing a `Server.MapPath` call to the relative URL you expect to exist (again you'll find this in the `HttpContext` object) and if the mapping is not successful you could then assume that a specific subfolder as specified by your relative path does not exist.