# How to access files in a webapp when querying IIS using System.DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, path, active-directory

**Environment:**

- C#
- IIS6 or IIS7 with compatibility mode

.

**What I'm trying to do:**

Find a particular IIS Web Application and then

- Shut down the parent website
- Add/Replace/Remove files in the physical path of the web application (i.e. applying an update)
- Start up the parent website

.

**This is what I've got:**

```
 DirectoryEntry IIsEntities = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC");

        foreach (DirectoryEntry IIsSite in IIsEntities.Children)
        {
            if (IIsSite.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer")
            {
                foreach (DirectoryEntry IIsEntity in IIsSite.Children)
                {
                    if (IIsEntity.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebVirtualDir")
                    {
                        foreach (DirectoryEntry IIsApp in IIsEntity.Children)
                        {

                            yield return new IISWebsite
                                (
                                IIsSite.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString(),
                                IIsApp.Name,
                                IIsApp.Path,
                                (ServerState) IIsSite.Properties["ServerState"].Value
                                );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This feeds a ComboBox where the user can select the site that they want to be updated. So far, so good. But the `IIsApp.Path` gives me a path like `IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Website` which I cannot use with `Directory.GetFiles` or similar.

.

**What I'm looking for:**

A way to update files in a web application by converting the virtual path to a physical path. But maybe I don't even need to convert it if I can use the virtual path to replace files...

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431713/how-to-get-the-iis-virtual-dir-web-applications-physical-paths-with-c-sharp-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it...

```
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\MicrosoftIISv2", "SELECT * FROM IIsWebVirtualDirSetting");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
           result.Add(queryObj["Path"]);
        }
```