# How to get the server name and hosted site name of any site hosted in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dll, iis-7

I have hosted one site in IIS and ran the application. I have one exe which performs operation after reading the entries from MSMQ. So basically application add the task in MSMQ and exe reads that task and executes it.

I have one separate dll also in that dll I am preparing some href link of html dynamically. For doing this I need server dns and hosted sitename.

*Ex: http://localhost/mysite/login.aspx* from this url I need only http://localhost/mysite.

I am using this custom dll in one of task that exe executes.

**Now the problem is I don't know how to get dns and site name because custom dll won't have HttpContext.Current object.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GetHostEntry` together with `GetHostName` to get the DNS host name of the machine on which you make the call.

```
var hostname = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).HostName;
```

To get the IIS virtual directory, follow the directions explained in the OS post [How to get the IIS virtual dir & web application's physical paths with C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431713/how-to-get-the-iis-virtual-dir-web-applications-physical-paths-with-c-sharp-c):

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();

// get the site (e.g. default)
Site site = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Default Web Site");

// get the application that you are interested in
Application myApp = site.Applications["/Dev1"];

// get the physical path of the virtual directory
Console.WriteLine(myApp.VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath);
```

Comment: this will get me the hostname, but how I will get the virtual directory name of application which is hosted in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

You look for that asp.net function

[GetHostEntry(string hostNameOrAddress)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx)

There are also other commercial libraries that contains similar functions like [aspNetDns](http://www.aspnetdns.com/) that I prefer.

Comment: this will get me the hostname, but how I will get the virtual directory name of application which is hosted in IIS?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure I fully understood your problem, but what about to save URL you need in PATH on server and read it in your DLL?

Comment: How this is logical ? "I don't understand the problem but here is the answer..." and programming is about logic

Comment: You should use comment section if you need more information on question, and should write the answer when you have one.